# Comparator и метод compare

Tags: java

Помогите понять логику выполнения программы. У нас есть 3 массива стрингов, они записаны в ArrayList, я сортирую их по количеству элементов в листе. То чего я не могу понять: как происходит эта сортировка? 
Что здесь происходит?

```
Comparator<String[]> sortByLength = new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                return o1.length - o2.length;
            }
        };
```

> ---

```
public class T{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array1 = {"мама", "мыла", "раму"};
        String[] array2 = {"я", "очень", "люблю", "java"};
        String[] array3 = {"мир", "труд", "май"};

        List<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
        arrays.add(array1);
        arrays.add(array2);
        arrays.add(array3);

        Comparator<String[]> sortByLength = new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                return o1.length - o2.length;
            }
        };
arrays.sort(sortByLength);
        for (String[] str : arrays) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сортировка у вас происходит тут `arrays.sort(sortByLength);`
`arrays` это у вас объект `ArrayList` у него есть метод `sort` которому для сортировки вы передаете объект реализующий интерфейс `Comparator`

В данный коде блока

```
Comparator<String[]> sortByLength = new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
        return o1.length - o2.length;
    }
};
```

вы реализуете анонимный класс используя интерфейс `Comparator` у него есть метод `compare` который принимает два объекта и для сортировки возращяет.
**0** : если объекты равны
**-1** (не обязательно -1, должно быть любое отрицательное число) : если o1 < o2
**1** (любое положительное число) : если o1 > o2

UDP.
Это код старый. до Java 8.
В Java 8 появились **лямба функции** которые дают более элегантный код, например так:

```
arrays.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.length - o2.length);
/// или 
arrays.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.length));
```

Comment: Спасибо, я вот как раз пытаюсь разобраться с лямбда выражениями. А не могли бы Вы еще подсказать, как передаются массивы строк в метод compare, я имею ввиду, что параметров в нём всего два (String[] o1, String[] o2), как же перебираются все элементы списка тогда? Или здесь всё дело в реализации метода sort?

Comment: @Makaroni если в IDEA кликнут на метод `sort`, то можно посмотреть его реализацию. и там это реализовано. В интерфейсе `List` происходит переобход

Answer (score 2):

Компаратор сравнивает текущее значение и следующее.
То есть у вас сравненине будет примерно такое

```
{"я", "очень", "люблю", "java"} > {"мама", "мыла", "раму"} = 1
{"мир", "труд", "май"} < {"я", "очень", "люблю", "java"} = -1
{"мир", "труд", "май"} < {"я", "очень", "люблю", "java"} = 1
{"мама", "мыла", "раму"} < {"мир", "труд", "май"} = 0
```

На основании этих значений, компоратор поставит в порядке возрастания в зависимости от длины массива.

```
[мама, мыла, раму]
[мир, труд, май]
[я, очень, люблю, java]
```

Comment: Не надо врать по поводу "текущее значение и **следующее**". Можно подумать, что компаратор идет по массиву и сравнивает 2 соседних элемента

Comment: @AndrewBystrov и как же тогда тут происходит обход по всем массивам?

Comment: все зависит от сортировки, которая применяется. компаратор с легкостью может брать первый и последний элементы. Я написал коммент именно к слову "следующее"